# Cannot deserialize generic class hierarchy using Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm receiving, for instance, this JSON from an external vendor (where `payload` can be variable):

```
{
  "payload": {
    "enrolledAt": "2018-11-05T00:00:00-05:00",
    "userId": "99c7ff5c-2c4e-423f-abeb-2e5f3709a42a"
  },
  "requestId": "80517bb8-2a95-4f15-9a73-fcf3752a1147",
  "eventType": "event.success",
  "createdAt": "2018-11-05T16:55:13.762-05:00"
}
```

I'm trying to model these using this class:

```
public final class Notification<T extends AbstractModel> {
  @JsonProperty("requestId")
  private String requestId;

  @JsonProperty("eventType")
  private String eventType;

  @JsonProperty("createdAt")
  private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

  private T payload;

  @JsonCreator
  public Notification(@JsonProperty("payload") T payload) {
    requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    eventType = payload.getType();
    createdAt = ZonedDateTime.now();
    this.payload = payload;
  }

  // getters
}
```

...and then having these possible (generic) types:

```
public abstract class AbstractModel {
  private String userId;

  private Type type;

  @JsonCreator
  AbstractModel(@JsonProperty("companyUserId") String userId, @JsonProperty("type") Type type) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.type = type;
  }

  // getters

  public enum Type {
    CANCEL("event.cancel"),
    SUCCESS("event.success");

    private final String value;

    Type(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() { return value; }
  }
}
```

---

```
public final class Success extends AbstractModel {
  private ZonedDateTime enrolledAt;

  @JsonCreator
  public Success(String userId, @JsonProperty("enrolledAt") ZonedDateTime enrolledAt) {
    super(userId, Type.SUCCESS);
    this.enrolledAt = enrolledAt;
  }

  // getters
}
```

---

```
public final class Cancel extends AbstractModel {
  private ZonedDateTime cancelledAt;

  private String reason;

  @JsonCreator
  public Cancel(String userId, @JsonProperty("cancelledAt") ZonedDateTime cancelledAt,
      @JsonProperty("reason") String reason) {
    super(userId, Type.CANCEL);
    this.cancelledAt = cancelledAt;
    this.reason = reason;
  }

  // getters
}
```

The application is based on Spring Boot, so I'm deserializing the JSON like:

```
@Component
public final class NotificationMapper {    
  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  public NotificationMapper(final ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }

  public Optional<Notification<? extends AbstractModel>> deserializeFrom(final String thiz) {
    try {
      return Optional.of(mapper.readValue(thiz, new NotificationTypeReference()));
    } catch (final Exception e) { /* log errors here */ }
    return Optional.empty();
  }

  private static final class NotificationTypeReference extends TypeReference<Notification<? extends AbstractModel>> { }
}
```

...but eventually since I'm posting this right here, Jackson doesn't like any of that so far. I've tried several things like: `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes`, but I can't change the JSON input.

Anyone? Any clue(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up adding another key/value pair in the JSON – the contract was indeed modified a little bit to accommodate that "private" key/value pair.

In any case, if somebody runs into the same issue, this is the solution for the approach:

```
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("_type")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "_type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cancel.class, name = "_type"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Fail.class, name = "_type"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Success.class, name = "_type"),
})
public abstract class AbstractModel {
  private String userId;

  private Type type;

  AbstractModel() { }

  AbstractModel(final String userId, final Type type) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.type = type;
  }

  // getters, toString, etc.

  public enum Type {
    CANCEL("event.cancelled"),
    FAIL("event.failed"),
    SUCCESS("event.success");

    private final String value;

    Type(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() { return value; }
  }
}
```