# Java Jackson Serialize List of Abstract Class

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

## Scenario

Imagine that I have an abstract class named `InfoItem`, that each class that inherits from it is a different type of Info Type that is used later to help me with the classification.

Each `InfoItem` have a `timestamp` as a property (when does this `InfoItem` arrive )?

**Note**: I'm using *Lombok* in this example

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, visible = true, property = "@type")
public abstract class InfoItem {
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
}
```

I have 2 classes that extend this class: `Alpha` and `Beta`.
Each class has multiple properties that don't have a common property between them:

```
@JsonTypeName("alpha")
@Data
public class Alpha extends InfoItem {
    private int x;
    private long y;
}

@JsonTypeName("beta")
@Data
public class Beta extends InfoItem {
    private bool isOk;
}
```

Now imagine that I create a list of `InfoItem` items:

```
list[0] = Alpha(x = 10, y = 20)
list[1] = Beta(isOk = false)
```

## Issue

If the list above is saved as a variable named `lst`, and then I'd run this command:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(lst);
System.out.println(s);
```

I'd get this:

```
[
    {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 20
    },
    {
        "isOk": false
    }
]
```

instead of:

```
[
    {
        "@type": "alpha",
        "x": 10,
        "y": 20
    },
    {
        "@type": "beta",
        "isOk": false
    }
]
```

It happens when I run the `ObjectMapper` over a `List` directly, and not a class that I create and put in it a list.

### Case: List in a class that I created

If I create a class named `FooBar` that have a property `lst`(type List` - same as above):

```
@Data
public class FooBar {
    private List<InfoItem> items;
}
```

and then I do:

```
FooBar bar = new FooBar();
bar.setItems(lst);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(lst);
System.out.println(s);
```

I'd get:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "@type": "alpha",
            "x": 10,
            "y": 20
        },
        {
            "@type": "beta",
            "isOk": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found after a few days a solution:

```
public static <T> Optional<String> toJson(final ObjectMapper mapper, final TypeReference<T> type, final T object) {
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.writer().forType(type).writeValueAsString(object));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<InfoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    // Set values in items...

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Optional<String> json = toJson(mapper, new TypeReference<List<InfoItem>>() {}, items);
    json.ifPresent(x -> System.out.println(x));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done if you annotate your `abstract` class with something like this (you might need to tweak it to your needs):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "_type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Alpha.class, name = "_type"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Beta.class, name = "_type"),
})
```

When you generate the JSON that will insert a `_type` key with the value of the FQDN class for `Alpha`, `Beta`, etc. It should work similar for your use case.

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163256/cannot-deserialize-generic-class-hierarchy-using-jackson/) helps for some more background. I was doing something similar a while back – I haven't updated the question though :)

Comment: Besides, you cannot put `Alpha` as a class object in `@JsonSubTypes` due to the fact that Java demands you to do `Alpha.class`

Comment: ...well, that was a typo, it's actually the `Class<T>` what goes in there, so `Alpha.class` is the correct thing. Also, you must have an empty (no args) constructor for this to work. You are using Lombok, so it's easy to forget.